# In Ember, is there a helper to get a path? (Without link-to)

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-router

For historical reasons, I can't easily use `{{#link-to}}`; I am dealing with an `<a>` tag, and want to do something like `<a href="{{path-to 'dashboard'}}">`.

My perusal of Ember docs indicates this… doesn’t exist. Can that be right? Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Instead of figuring out the path, can you perhaps simulate what `{{link-to}}` does by making each `a` call an action that will call `transitionToRoute` with a proper route name?

Comment: Also, is your `'dashboard'` a route name or a url path?

Comment: Have you seen [ember-href-to](https://github.com/intercom/ember-href-to)? There's also a [routing service RFC](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/router-service/text/0000-router-service.md) being developed.

Comment: Did you know that link-to creates an `a` tag by default?

Comment: Yes, I’m aware that it creates an `a` tag and would exploit this if it weren’t necessary to maintain the `{{action}}` already being applied to an `<a>` tag. I ended up using `{{unbound}}` and properties on a controller (old Ember version alert!) to get paths from the router.

Comment: I wanted real links, not simulated ones. This is big for accessibility, and even just for the ability to open a link in a new tab.